# How to install bpython for python3 on OSX?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, python, easy-install

How can I install bpython, or another good python shell, on OSX 10.6, **for python 3**?

Calling `easy_install bpython` installed it for python 2.6 (same with ipython). Nor brew nor macports seem to even realise python 3 exists. Directly trying ipython's egg specific for python 3 gave all sort of errors.

Comment: Homebrew has `python3`, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, just running `easy_install` uses Python 2.  If you have the Python 3 version of `distribute` installed, you can run `easy_install3 bpython` to install `bpython` into Python 3.  If not, [download and install it](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#distribute-setup-py) so you can use `easy_install` with Python 3 whenever you need it.

Alternatively, just [download the `bpython` tarball](http://bpython-interpreter.org/downloads/), extract it, and then run `sudo python3 setup.py` in the extracted directory to install it.

IPython for Python 3 is not available through `easy_install`/`pip` so you have to [download its tarball](http://ipython.org/download.html) and install it the same way as `bpython`.

Comment: It requred a few guesses, but in the end doing it via distribute worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually pretty easy to install bpython on OSX. All you have to do is type one of the following commands into the terminal. Depending on whether you have python2 or python3 the pip commands vary. If you are using python3, use this command to install bpython:

```
pip3 install bpython
```

If you are using python2, use this command to install bpython:

```
pip install bpython
```

That should get bpython installed on OSX. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's available on pip (https://pypi.org/project/bpython/)
so you can install via:

`sudo pip install bpython`